# Taking macro argument inside a different macro in C

Tags: c, macros

Why this is not giving the desired output ? For Ex - take a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4 It is giving MAX4() = 2 while it should be 4 in this case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX4(a,b,c,d) MAX2(MAX2(a,b),MAX2(c,d))
#define MAX2(a,b) a>b?a:b 

int a,b,c,d;

int main(){

    /*printf("Please enter 2 integers - \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);   
    printf("The maximum number among them is %d\n",MAX2(a,b));
    */
    printf("Please enter 4 integers - \n");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d",&a,&b,&c,&d);   
    printf("The maximum number among them is %d\n",MAX4(a,b,c,d));//,MAX2(a,b),MAX2(c,d));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis to enforce the order of evaluation:

```
#define MAX2(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

The extra parenthesis around arguments are needed to allow for expressions like `MAX2(a + 1, b + 2)`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know this.

Answer (score 3):

Macros just do text replacement.  So the `MAX4` call first expands macros in its arguments, giving

```
    MAX2(a>b?a:b,c>d?c:d)
```

which then expands to

```
    a>b?a:b>c>d?c:d?a>b?a:b:c>d?c:d
```

When the compiler then parses the expanded macro, the precedence of `>` (higher than `?:`) causes this to not do what you expect.  Using extra parentheses in the macro can avoid the precedence problem, but you may still have problems if you call your `MAX2` macro on expressions with side effects.

Comment: And if you can't do `a>b?a:b>c>d?c:d?a>b?a:b:c>d?c:d` in your head, you can't call yourself a programmer! Beat me to the answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your macro

```
MAX4(a,b,c,d);
```

if a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4 then the macro becomes

```
MAX4(1,2,3,4);
```

which would in turn will become

```
MAX2(MAX2(1,2),MAX2(3,4))
```

So it is evaluated as

```
MAX2(1>2?1:2,3>4?3:4)
```

i.e

```
1>2?1:2>3>4?3:4?1>2?1:2:3>4?3:4
```

and and according to operator precedence and associativity you get 2 and not 4.

In order to get 4 you should use

```
#define MAX2(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```